# Why is hermitivity not preserved when Fourier transforming a matrix?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, linear-algebra

Consider a somewhat big Hamiltonian matrix $H$.
I wanted to get its momentum representation, so I took the discrete Fourier transform or more specifically applied a FFT algorithm on it using Python. This produced a new matrix $K$. However, $K$ wasn't hermitian. I did check that $H$ was hermitian. Since the Fourier transform is just mapping to a different space and representation which conserves things like the energies and eigenstates, how is that it affects the hermitian property of the Hamiltonian?

Comment: My guess is there is a bug in your code. How big is the deviation from a Hermitian matrix? If it is small it may simply be a numerical error. Otherwise double check your code, check that the FFT routine is doing *exactly* what you think it's doing, check that you are applying it correctly to the matrix, etc.

Comment: I was using a specific Quantum python toolbox that automatically checks if the matrix is hermitian or not so I took that matrix and passed it through the standard SciPy FFT method. Not too sure of the deviation. When I tried to find the eigenvalues of the FFT of the original Hamiltonian all but two of the eigenvalues were complex valued which pretty significant imaginary components (as in none were even remotely close to $0$)

Comment: Seems like I forgot to do the FFT along both rows and columns, but after doing that the matrix is still not Hermitian; however, most of the eigenvalues are approximately real (imaginary components with order of magnitude ~$10^{-15}$ but theres usually two eigenvalues with imaginary components with order of magnitude $10^1$

Comment: What Hamiltonian is this?

Comment: @MsTais What do you mean?

Comment: @Sam What are the symmetries? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @MsTais I'm modeling a molecule through group theory and optics, the symmetries so far is that one can decompose the matrix into matrix of cyclic block matrices. So it wraps around itself

Comment: @Sam So it is a central potential... In which coordinate system are you working? Can you associate your broken eigenvalues to particular degrees of freedom or spatial dimensions? Also, please, if you solve the problem, give an update here, if you don't mind.

Comment: @MsTais so my basis is of the following format (the letters here are arbitrary) $|b,d,m \rangle$ where b refers to a single bond or double bond, d refers to whether a particle is moving left or right and m refers to the position of the particle, or more specifically which pair of atoms the particle is residing upon. Let me know if you need more details or if it's vague

Comment: @Sam Since it sounds like you have a mixture of rotational and translational degrees of freedom, Fourier transform (linear transformation) may produce artifacts. You have implicitly chosen a cartesian basis in your FFT. Now, mapping of cartesian on, say, spherical is not 1-to-1&onto. I don't have enough training to tell you more. I suspect that it might be, but is not necessarily a bug.

Comment: @Sam I would say, mathematically, you are probably allowed to FFT the eigenfunctions, but not a Hamiltonian itself. But take this with a grain of salt. This question is more for mathematicians, I think.